# What's the advantage of using Zend_Db Models over mysqli?

Tags: php, zend-framework, mysqli, zend-db

I've just started using ZF and there's some very handy libraries that save me a lot of time but I can't see the advantage in using their Zend_DB class over mysqli. I don't need PDO as I will always use MySQL as DBMS. And really, how often do you change your DBMS in the middle of a project anyway?

And I'm very comfortable with SQL so don't need their abstraction which just confuses me.

So what advantage is there over this mysqli code in my class constructors and then just SQL queries when I need them?

```
require_once("database_details.php");
$this->_mysql=new mysqli(DBSERVERHOST,DBUSERNAME,DBPASSWORD,DBNAME);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I donno ZF, but bare mysqli is just ugly. What is your code to get some rows to populate a template?
Let's assume it's just as doleful as

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM myCity WHERE Name=? AND CountryCode=? AND District=?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $val1, $val2, $val3);
$stmt->execute();
$data = array();
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

(that's just plain example from the manual, with no obligatory things like error handling)

While with some library you can make it like

```
$data=$db->getArr("SELECT * FROM myCity WHERE Name=? AND CountryCode=? AND District=?"
                   $val1, $val2, $val3);
```

just count number of queries in your usual script and feel the difference.

Also note that you have your precious SQL intact!

Comment: I suppose that does look a bit more elegant. I had to look up doleful in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of advantages. I don't know all of them, but two are just outstanding:

**1) Adapter Dependency / Code Independency**
No matter what Database you use - the code for your Queries NEVER changes.

```
$db->select()->where('a=?', $b)->order('C DESC')->limit(5);
```

It doesn't matter if your adapter is MySQL, PGSQL, MSSQL, etc... i think even some NoSQL-Databases are supported with the same query formats by Zend

**2) Caching**
When using a Library for Queries - especially with Zend or Doctrine (combineable!) - caching your DB Queries is a piece of cake. Do this manually for each of your Queries and you're doomed to have looooots of Code :P

**3) Readability**
Personally i just feel that using a Library (can be your own one, too) has lots of advantages for readability, too

Comment: 1) is not a real advantage, as mentioned by the OP and 2) should be not as dumb as caching query result, bit more intelligent, driven at the controller level.

Comment: Well the OP might be right in a sense that a running project doesn't change its DBMS. But when a new Project ships and a client specifically wants a different DBMS, then you don't have to rethink everything. Just provide a different Adapter and then you just do what you're always doing. No new functions, all the same old stuff :) And obviously 2) can be more - this was just a given example

Comment: 1 and 3 - yes. Caching no, as my applications rarely hit more than 100 users (lil internal stuff only - sadly)

Comment: I mean 1. Shat databases you have switched?

Comment: As mentioned previously, a running Project doesn't change its DB. But i had to use Postgres twice.